# Windows 8 - Animation in c#?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Well it seems the standard DoubleAnimation doesn't work anymore - Duration has no parameters.

Is there any way of writing animations programatically rather than XAML?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 8 - BeginAnimation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631088/windows-8-beginanimation)

Comment: Please stop reposting the same question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can no longer create a duration directly. You need to use a helper class to create the duration.

```
d.Duration = DurationHelper.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```