# Windows 8 - BeginAnimation?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

It seems I can't do `myObject.BeginAnimation(dp , animation)`.

Is this a bug or has it been changed?

Comment: please post what code you have so we may be able to see how you are instantiating myObject

Comment: It doesn't matter what object. Even Button myButton = new Button() doesn't have the BeginAnimation method. I'm not sure whether this was changed or my installation is broken...

Comment: @HarisHasan So are there any alternatives? How else can I use my DoubleAnimation?

Comment: I would suggest see animation samples http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-Developer-Preview-6b53adbb

Comment: @HarisHasan thanks but none of them show how to do it in code. They are XAML animations

Comment: BeginAnimation is a method of Storyboard class. So unless if your object is a storyboard then it is not a bug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a storyboard. Add your animation to the storyboard and have the storyboard begin the animation.

```
var storyboard = new Storyboard();

var opacityAnimation = new DoubleAnimation { 
    From = 0,
    To = 1,
    Duration = DurationHelper.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)),
};
storyboard.Children.Add(opacityAnimation);

Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(opacityAnimation, "Opacity");
Storyboard.SetTarget(storyboard, myObject);

storyboard.Begin();
```